# Newrelic + sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, newrelic

How  to turn on track of postgres queries via sqlalchemy in newrelic monitoring?

I have app with sqlalchemy ORM and add newrelic to it, but newrelic don't catch sql queries via ORM.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't cache? Are you using a framework such as django or flask?

Comment: i use iasyncio+aiohttp + raw sqlalchemy

Comment: seems they don't have such instrumented integration 
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/getting-started/instrumented-python-packages

Comment: sorry, miss word 'catch' not 'cache'

Answer (score 0):

In my case all start works with `transaction_tracer.record_sql = raw` in `newrelic.ini` unfortunatly there was problems with `obfuscated`

```
# When the transaction tracer is on, SQL statements can
# optionally be recorded. The recorder has three modes, "off"
# which sends no SQL, "raw" which sends the SQL statement in its
# original form, and "obfuscated", which strips out numeric and
# string literals.
transaction_tracer.record_sql = raw
```